# Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|$ is integrable, then:

(a) Each $f_n$ is integrable

(b) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges a.e. and is integrable

(c) $\int_\Bbb{R}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_nd\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_\Bbb{R}f_nd\mu$

Since  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|$ is integrable, we have that  $\int|f_n|\leq \int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|<\infty$ and that each $\int|f_n|$ is finite hence, $f$ is integrable.

But I'm lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |f_n|$ is integrable then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |f_n| < \infty$ a.e, that is, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n$ converges absolutely a.e $\implies$ converges a.e. Now, if we put $g_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k$ a.k.a the $n$-th partial sum of the series, we know that $g_n \to g = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n$ a.e. Moreover,
$$
|g_n| = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} |f_k| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |f_k|,
$$
which is integrable. Then, by the Domianted Convergence Theorem, $g$ is integrable and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k \, d\mu =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} g_n \, d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}}g \,d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \,d\mu.
$$

Comment: Why does that imply the series converges absolutely a.e.?

Comment: What does it mean to a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge absolutely?

Comment: Shoot. That was a stupid question. It means that the sum of the absolute values is finite. And obviously this would imply $f_n$ converges. Thank you!